# Create multiple consumers for same topic in kafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I am newbie and can see one example with one consumer in below github repository, but any ideas how to create multiple consumers for same topic in go lang?

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/tree/master/examples

Any consumer factory (to generate N consumers) available in confluent-kafka to read same topic (with partitions)?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Ullaakut I am checking if any consumer factory would be available to create N number of consumers for same topic (with different partitions) in confluent kafka? Updated my question.

Comment: Again, what have you tried, though? For example, try to create a list of consumer objects and assign them all a given partition? Generally, one application only runs one consumer, though. Then you scale your application independently

Comment: @cricket_007, any reason why one application should run one consumer. I see having partitions can improve the data processing time. I was able to get the partition count in topic, create multiple consumers and read the data from different partitions and it worked with small data. Just need to tweak code in this example, https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/consumer_example/consumer_example.go

Comment: For simplicity? Scalable microservices? Rather than having one machine become a bottleneck, you distribute it over many. Otherwise, one application is already assigned all the partitions for a given topic. If you actually need two distinct topics, I've only seen that being done in Kafka Streams were you would first join the topics on some field

Comment: Seems like a microservice anti-pattern to have 1 application/service consuming messages from the same topic and handling it differently. Surely the SOLID Single Responsibility principle would lead one to have 1 service consuming 1 topic for 1 path of execution? Doing 1 thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the Confluent github repo :

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/consumer_example/consumer_example.go

If you want to create multiple consumers for the same topic, there are two scenarios :

1.Create each consumer with different group id.

```
c1, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers":    broker,
        "group.id":             group1,
        "session.timeout.ms":   6000,
        "default.topic.config": kafka.ConfigMap{"auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}})

c2, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers":    broker,
        "group.id":             group2,
        "session.timeout.ms":   6000,
        "default.topic.config": kafka.ConfigMap{"auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}})
```

2. If you want multiple consumers for the same topic but with the same group id, it will start consuming from single partition. i.e. A topic contains 3 partitions and you create 3 consumers with same group id, each consumer will consume from one partition

Comment: I am checking if any consumer factory would be available to create N number of consumers for same topic (with different partitions) ?